# Issue: Joining two views in MySQL

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench

I have two views and I want to retrieve their data in a single dataset. I know I have to use join but I am not getting the proper result.

**View1 data:**

```
id1 | col1 | col2 | col3 

1   | abc  | xyz | err

2   | pqr  | foo | err10
```

**View2 data:**

```
id2 | col1 | col2 | col4

1   | abc | xyz | tmp1

2   | xyz | rst | tmp10

3   | xyz | test | tmp5
```

**Expected Result:**

```
col1 | col2 | col3 | col4

abc  | xyz | err | NULL

abc  | xyz | NULL | tmp1

pqr  | foo | err10 | NULL

xyz | rst | NULL | tmp10

xyz | test | NULL | tmp5
```

`col1 and col2` should not display twice, all the entries should come in the same column.

I am using MySQL 5.5.8

Comment: Did you try anything? if so please post the code also

Comment: I simply tried to join both the views using join statement:

select * from View1 join View2;

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like a standard union all to me:

```
select col1, col2, col3, NULL as col4
  from view1
 union all
select col1, col2, NULL as col3, col4
  from view2
```

To get the ordering from your output, you can specify an order by clause as such:

```
select * from (

   select col1, col2, col3, NULL as col4
     from view1
    union all
   select col1, col2, NULL as col3, col4
     from view2

) a order by col1
```

See also the [SQLFiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/94dc5/5)

Comment: Thanks for your time. Specially for "NULL as"

Answer (score 1):

you need this:

```
SELECT 
col1, col2, col3, NULL AS col4
FROM view1
UNION 
SELECT 
col1, col2, NULL AS col3, col4
FROM view2
```